# jQuery undefined value click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some forms with custom id's.
All of them has some of the hidden fields and one number and submit field. I would like to get the number field's value in a variable with this function

```
$(".formclass").click(function () {
    console.log(this.id);
    var id = this.id;
    var value = $(id).find("input[type='number']").val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

The return output in the console is

> form-103
>
> undefined

tried with `.children()` or `.attr('value')`, none of them worked.

here is an example:

```
<form id="form-<?=$id_val?>" class="formclass"
enctype="multipart/form-data"
method="POST"
action="/etlap/">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart"
    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($pid); ?>"/>
    <input type="number" id="quantity"
    name="quantity" min="1"
    required="required"
    pattern="[0-9]*"
    max=<?= $floor_available_stock ?>
    inputmode="numeric"
    value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id"
    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($getvar1); ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart"/>
</form>
```

Comment: That would seem to indicate that the find is not finding an element.  Which this is confusing me.  Why are you grabbing the id of the thing you clicked, to then look it up?  You already have it.  `this` is your element.  `$(this).find(....).val()` would effectively be the same thing.

Comment: `$(id)` is pointless. just use `$(this)`. and lose all the id stuff.

Comment: Yeah, the reason it's not working, even though you should not do it like that, is the `id` would be like `myId` and `$('myId')` isn't a valid lookup

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to find the number inside the element you clicked you can simply do

```
$("input[type='number']", this).val();
```

When using this version of the selector, the second element will be the parent that is used to search children of.  Normal selectors are effectively wrappers around `$(selector, document)`

Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried but may be you should use a css selector in the line 4. Try using the selector like :
`var value = $("#"+id).find("input[type='number']").val();`